# Cors throws me error "Acces is Denied"

Tags: c#, jquery, iis, sharepoint, cors

I have built an SharePoint app, that calls with Jquery a Webservice hosted in IIS.

The SharePoint Server specialy the app will be hosted in SharePoint under the domain

```
https://qsspapp-3b9352b780820d.qsapps.com/teams/...
```

My call looks like the following

```
private loadStates() {      
         $.support.cors = true; 
         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             cache: false,
             crossDomain:true,
             url: "http://myservice.de/api/controller/getavailablestates",
             success: (results) => {
                 console.log(results.Data);
                 this.availableStates.removeAll();
                 $.each(results.Data, (indexedDB, item: TableResultItem) => {

                     this.availableStates.push(new DataObjects.SelectionItem(item.rEQSTField, item.rEQST_DSCRField));
                 });

             },
             error: (jqXHR: any, textStatus: any, errorThrown: any) => {

                 console.log("loadStates Error: " + errorThrown);
             },

         });

     }
```

My Service Web.config contains the following setting for cors:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>

    <customHeaders>

      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>...
```

When I call this method it thows me the Error "Acces is Denied".

What do i wrong?

Comment: I hope you need to mention the Username credentials in ajax request

Comment: Yes but I have no authentication routines for now. So that could not be the problem. Anonymous access is also granted for the service.

Comment: No your error clearly mention that the problem is with authentication, so that why you got "Acces is Denied". I hope you need to check the server once again

Comment: @AntoKing "Access is denied" most likely has nothing to do with authentication in this case. I'd guess there is no support for "OPTIONS" verb on your server and hence no CORS. Use Fiddler to see what requests are actually made and what headers are actually sent.

Answer (score 0):

Use below in **webconfig**

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="None" />
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution to work.

**The Problem**

I work on an HTTPS System (SharePoint) and make a call to a HTTP System (Service Dispatcher).
This works in the most browsers, but not in IE.... (bad thing..)

**The solution:**

I must create a HTTP Binding for the Service Dispatcher and also add the Dispatcher Url as thrusted site.

After that it works.

Thx for your help! :)